# Heroku Deployment Issues ([remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs)

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm currently following along with Heroku's '[Getting Started With Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)' tutorial. I keep running into the same issue on deployment, as I will paste below:

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 312, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (276/276), done.
Writing objects: 100% (312/312), 84.34 KiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done.
Total 312 (delta 130), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.2
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting antiorm==1.2.1 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading antiorm-1.2.1.tar.gz (171kB)
remote:        Collecting appengine==1.8.0.2 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading appengine-1.8.0.2.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting astroid==1.4.9 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading astroid-1.4.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (213kB)
remote:        Collecting autopep8==1.3.2 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Downloading autopep8-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42kB)
remote:        Collecting Babel==2.4.0 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Downloading Babel-2.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.8MB)
remote:        Collecting backports.functools-lru-cache==1.3 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 6))
remote:          Downloading backports.functools_lru_cache-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 7))
remote:          Downloading backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting bcrypt==3.1.3 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 8))
remote:          Downloading bcrypt-3.1.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54kB)
remote:        Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.5.3 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 9))
remote:          Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (85kB)
remote:        Collecting bleach==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading bleach-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting blinker==1.4 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 11))
remote:          Downloading blinker-1.4.tar.gz (111kB)
remote:        Collecting certifi==2017.7.27.1 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 12))
remote:          Downloading certifi-2017.7.27.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (349kB)
remote:        Collecting cffi==1.9.1 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 13))
remote:          Downloading cffi-1.9.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (398kB)
remote:        Collecting chardet==3.0.4 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 14))
remote:          Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133kB)
remote:        Collecting click==6.7 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 15))
remote:          Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
remote:        Collecting colorama==0.3.7 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 16))
remote:          Downloading colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting configparser==3.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 17))
remote:          Downloading configparser-3.5.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting coverage==4.4.1 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 18))
remote:          Downloading coverage-4.4.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (196kB)
remote:        Collecting db==0.1.1 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 19))
remote:          Downloading db-0.1.1.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting decorator==4.0.11 (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 20))
remote:          Downloading decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting distribute (from -r /tmp/build_667882a487f7eae4c46277a382f6b6f1/requirements.txt (line 21))
remote:          Downloading distribute-0.7.3.zip (145kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command.install import install
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
remote:                from setuptools.command import install_scripts
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
remote:                from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
remote:                register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
remote:            AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zc0gylhz/distribute/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
```

I've already updated my setup tools in pip and followed the advice of a few other articles that I've seen on here. I couldn't find my exact issue, so I wanted to put it out there.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Before running $git push heroku master run $git pull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines that start with "remote:" are echoed by the `pre-receive` hook in the remote repository. The remote repository runs the hook to check the files before accepting your push. It tries to build/parse the files and encounters an error `AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'`. Before the next push, you must fix the error, which is at `pkg_resources.py, line 1518`. After the fix, you could amend the last commit. If the hook checks every commit, you need to make sure that the files should have no build/parse errors after checking out any of the commits.

Comment: I would really hope that the server isn't trying to build *every* commit in the push... but I guess that's possible? Sounds like a lot of wasted processor power.

Comment: @JDB It's not a waste even if every commit is built. It would be annoying and frustrating to checkout a commit that can't work, especially in teamwork. Extra time and efforts would be spent in fixing the errors which could have been avoided earlier. The build procedure could be optimized to save resources.

Comment: I guess it depends on which branch and a team's workflow. My team uses issue branches that typically belong to one developer. We run a build, but only on the last commit pushed. Issues then get squashed to a single commit when merged with master. Other teams may have their own workflows.

Comment: @JDB Your team is using a good strategy. But I think then every commit on `master` should be built to make sure all of them can work.