# Git Heroku error [remote rejected] ... (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: python, git, heroku

I'm trying to push my repo to my heroku stack but this error comes everytime up:

```
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-project.git'
```

This is the full comandline log for Python version 3.8.0:

```
Enumerating objects: 36, done.
Counting objects: 100% (36/36), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (36/36), 4.63 MiB | 923.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 36 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/8790c95df255b386056ea169648fd4a33d1cb3fba81f73b536f26374f6af107145f64a5980db7a52177f63bb41527f360ebd2e3bef7b8917bda7b51cf284cfdb/bin/steps/python: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
remote:  !     Requested runtime (ÿþPython-3.8.0) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-heroku-project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/whatsapp-vertretungsplan-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-project.git'
```

This is the full comandline log for Python version 3.7.5:

```
Enumerating objects: 40, done.
Counting objects: 100% (40/40), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
Writing objects: 100% (40/40), 4.63 MiB | 910.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 40 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/8790c95df255b386056ea169648fd4a33d1cb3fba81f73b536f26374f6af107145f64a5980db7a52177f63bb41527f360ebd2e3bef7b8917bda7b51cf284cfdb/bin/steps/python: line 5: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
remote:  !     Requested runtime (ÿþPython-3.7.5) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-heroku-project.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/whatsapp-vertretungsplan-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-heroku-project.git'
```

(This is my first time working with Git and Heroku. So if the error is something obvious I'm sorry.)

Comment: But I've tried Python 3.7.5 and Python 2.7.17 and both don't work too, eventhough they are listed as supported on herokustack-18

Comment: Did you mean my new change to my question? (I'm sorry I don't really know what a minimal reproducible example would be in this case)

Comment: You should double-check your `runtime.txt`; `ÿþPython-3.7.5` doesn't meet the requirements in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes.

Comment: This is my runtime.txt:
`Python-3.7.5`

and on this website it is listed as a supported runtime:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support

Comment: Well 1. the docs note it's case sensitive; and 2. there are some extra characters coming from *somewhere*.

Comment: Now I've changed the runtime.txt to all lowercase but in the comandline it is sitll: `ÿþpython-3.7.5`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%C3%BF%C3%BE

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, the file was encoded with "UCS-2 LE-BOM", now i`ve convered it to UTF-8 encoding and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found out what the problem was.**

I think Heroku didn't support my encoding type, so it added some weird characters to my runtime.txt. But after a change to UTF-8 (I think, it was a long time ago) everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

How is Python written in the runtime.txt file? Python or python? This problem happened to me: I changed from Python-3.8.0 to python-3.8.0 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was this `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

I realised that i had been forgetting to add a requirements file.

After that, repeat the following in order.

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines that start with "remote:" are echoed by the pre-receive hook in the remote repository. The remote repository runs the hook to check the files before accepting your push. It tries to build/parse the files and encounters an error ...
You can find the complete answer here.
[Heroku Deployment Issues ([remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46966040/heroku-deployment-issues-remote-rejected-master-master-pre-receive-hook-d).

For my case I was trying to deploy a flask app but was missing a file containing the necessary dependencies. To correct the error I did this to generate a file with all the dependencies. "pip freeze > requirements.txt" and damn!. My problem was solved.

The following blog gives a detailed explanation of how to deploy a Flask app on Heroku.
https://medium.com/the-andela-way/deploying-a-python-flask-app-to-heroku-41250bda27d0

Answer (score 0):

**Review your Dashboard->YOUR_APP->Activity->ViewLogs**

You can find the exactly error message.

In my case I found this(**view image**), I had to **drop** my **package-lock.json** because also I had yarn.lock...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I realized that had forgotten to log to Heroku via the terminal. Then I updated the `requirements.txt` file.

This is what I did:

1. `heroku login`
2. `git add .`
3. `git commit -m "requirements.txt updates"`
4. `git push heroku master.`

It worked as I had expected.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked

First

```
$ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

after

```
$ git push heroku main
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating `runtime.txt` file and putting the version of python that I want (python-3.7.11) into this file and then placing it the same directory as `app.py`:

```
app.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases just disable you static file configuration with this:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue with the following steps:

- `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -am "make it better"`

Then finally I did the push again:

- `git push heroku master`

```
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting click==8.0.3
remote:          Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
remote:        Collecting Flask==2.0.2
remote:          Downloading Flask-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (95 kB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==20.1.0
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
remote:        Collecting itsdangerous==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
remote:        Collecting Jinja2==3.0.3
remote:          Downloading Jinja2-3.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
remote:        Collecting MarkupSafe==2.0.1
remote:          Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
remote:        Collecting Werkzeug==2.0.2
remote:          Downloading Werkzeug-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
remote:        Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Werkzeug, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, gunicorn, Flask
remote:        Successfully installed Flask-2.0.2 Jinja2-3.0.3 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 Werkzeug-2.0.2 click-8.0.3 gunicorn-20.1.0 itsdangerous-2.0.1
remote: -----> Skipping Django collectstatic since the env var DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC is set.
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 62.3M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v4
remote:        https://flask-heru.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/flask-heru.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```