# Heroku push: Failure with "Git push Heroku master" and "Buildpack" --> Python

Tags: python-3.x, heroku, git-push

I'm really messed up with this problem...and I searched already for a proper solution, but nothing so far worked. So, I hope someone could give me a hint!

I have already manually set the Buildpack to python! But he won't accept the .../python.gtz.
Thx!

```
(venv) jpt@MacBookProJT95 SMA % git push heroku master:main        
Enumerating objects: 16, done.
Counting objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 2.95 KiB | 1.47 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: dc06a64ffe6a009a19697612b27abbb653ef757d
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version dc06a64ffe6a009a19697612b27abbb653ef757d
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to first-murmeltier.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/first-murmeltier.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/first-murmeltier.git'
```

Comment: Did you check the python buildpack documentation? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python. It says you need a requirements.txt file. Do you have one? Did you commit it to git?

Comment: Yes - I have a requirements.txt file(in root). I followed all the instructions. It seems, that there might be a conflict between the used interpreter python 3.6.x (can´t figure out the exact version) and the version used for the Buildpack.

Comment: Got it! I defined the required python version as "Python 3.6.x" - but it must be "Python-3.6.x" (the dash is key!).

Answer (score 0):

> I defined the required python version as "Python 3.6.x" - but it must be "Python-3.6.x" (the dash is key!)

That is what "[Specifying a Python Runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes)" does indeed document, in [Specifying a Python version](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#specifying-a-python-version):

> By default, newly created Python apps use the python-3.9.6 runtime.
> You can also specify a different supported Python version.
>
> Supported runtimes
>
> - python-3.9.6 on all supported stacks
> - python-3.8.11 on all supported stacks
> - python-3.7.11 on all supported stacks
> - python-3.6.14 on all supported stacks

And, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58883920/6309), make sure the `runtime.txt` is correctly encoded.